# Sorting an array with own template compare function in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, compare

```
template <class T>
bool cmp(const T &a, const T &b){
    return a <= b;
}

template <class T>
void bubble_sort(T tablica[], int size, bool compare(T,T)){
    bool change = true;

    while(change){
        change = false;
        for(int i=0; i < size-1; ++i){
            if(compare(tablica[i+1], tablica[i])){
                zamien(tablica[i+1], tablica[i]);
                change = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work, I have errors:

```
'void bubble_sort(T [],int,bool (__cdecl *)(T,T))' : 
 could not deduce template argument for 'T []' from 'int [10]'  
'void bubble_sort(T [],int,bool (__cdecl *)(T,T))' :
 cannot use function template 'bool cmp(const T,const T)' as a function argument'
```

but when I replace a cmp function with that:

```
bool cmp(const int a, const int b){
    return a <= b;
}
```

Everything works fine.
How to change my cmp function to work with templates?

Comment: C++ does not have generics, it has templates. The two may look the same, but they work in fundamentally different ways.

Comment: Mine compiled when I changed `compare(T,T)` to `compare (const T &, const T &)` and commented out the `zamien` line. Changing `zamien` to `std::swap` produced correct results when the numbers were different at least.

Comment: @Jasper but you use templates to do generic programming :-)

Comment: I suppose. But C++ Templates is an ugly-ass bodybuilder who can lift cars, while generics are just an average Joe that happens to be good at dressing up...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the "compare" function parameter that `bubble_sort` expects is of type:

```
bool compare(T,T)
```

While the "cmp" function is of type:

```
bool compare(const T&,const T&)
```

In order to fix it, modify the "compare" parameter's type:

```
template <class T>
void bubble_sort(T tablica[], int size, bool compare(const T&,const T&)){
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: I have still that error: 'void bubble_sort(T [],int,bool (__cdecl *)(const T &,const T &))' : could not deduce template argument for 'T []' from 'int [10]' when I want to use it like: bubble_sort(tab, size, cmp), where tab[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}.

Comment: Ok, on ideone it works perfectly, but when I try to compile it in MS Visual 2010 I have errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handled with this problem:

```
int (*cmp_int)(int,int) = compare<int>;
bubble_sort(in, 5, cmp_int);
```

Now it should work fine in MS Visual.